# "to successfully complete" or "to complete successfully"?

Tags: grammar, infinitives, split

A Google search yields 41,200,000 results for the former but only 3,150,000 for the latter.

Are split infinitives really to boldly be avoided in English grammar, or are millions of people just unaware of / uncaring for their existence?

Comment: This has been covered here many times before. An on-site search would have been preferable. I'd just add that your Google results are heavily skewed by the fact that '... to successfully complete the course ...' sounds far more natural than '... to complete successfully the course ...' etc.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth not to mention that his search probably excludes '...to complete the course successfully...'

Comment: @msam Yes, but that's not part of OP's question.